# TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). I need help (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

##hardware
LED = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)

## GUI DEFINITONS
win = Tk()
win.title("LED Toggler")
myFont = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Helvetica", size = 12, weight = "bold")
#Event Functionds
def ledToggle():
    if GPIO.output(LED) == GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH):
        GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)
        
    else:
        GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH) 
        
    
#WIDGETS
ledButton = Button(win, text = 'Turn LED On', command = ledToggle, bg = 'bisque2', height = 1, width = 24)
ledButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

I am making a GUI button for my raspberry pi which turn on a led when the gui button is pressed. I am getting the error message that is in the title

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if GPIO.output(LED) == GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH):  //output should have two parameters.
        GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)
        
    else:
        GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH)
```

with

```
if GPIO.input(LED) == GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH):
        GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)
        
    else:
        GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Comment: That fixed it. When i press the button on the gui it turn on but it wont turn back off when i press it